# Mostrar dados de json

Tags: php, json, libcurl

Preciso recuperar os dados PONTOS e RODADA_ATUAL

O link do json é --> https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/time/slug/semtitulos

Esse é o nome do time que quero puxar os dados: semtitulos

Quando você acessa essa url aparece todos os dados do time, mas não consigo pegar os 2 valores que preciso e imprimir na tela, tentei da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

// EM file_get_contents

    $url = "https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/time/slug/semtitulos";

    $options = array(
        'http' => 
          array(
            'method' => 'GET', 
            'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)', 
            'timeout' => 1
            )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $jogadores = json_decode($response, true);    


    $jogadores['atletas']['pontos'];
    $jogadores['atletas']['rodada_atual'];

     echo $jogadores;

?>
```

Mas não objetive resultado, porém uso o mesmo esquema acima para lista os jogadores mais escalados --> https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/destaques 
e funciona normalmente. Alguém pode ajudar ???

Comment: Tira o índice `['atletas']`, deixa assim: `$jogadores['pontos'];` e `$jogadores['rodada_atual'];`

Comment: Obrigado Junior :)

Comment: Criei uma resposta só pra oficializar!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só você tirar o índice atletas já que essas informações estão vindo na raíz do json:

```
$pontos = $jogadores['pontos'];
$rodada = $jogadores['rodada_atual'];
```

[JsonFormatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) é um bom site pra você analisar melhor a estrutura do JSON.